# spring hibernate application taking more than 10 minutes to start on tomcat

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, tomcat

This is a big application with multiple maven modules, more than 500 beans. Each bean is having the dependency on one or many.

Few days before the application was able to run within 1 minute, but now **The problem is, an it is unable to start even in 10 minutes**. I have enabled debug mode log and **getting continuously below logs** for more than 7-8 minutes but at the end getting an error as unable to start tomcat.

```
 DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/util/List<Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;>; for parameter kinDetailsList
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding collectionElement type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/Unit; for parameter unit
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/Unit;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: com.param.entity.model.master.Unit(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key com.param.entity.model.master.Unit(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/sql/Timestamp; for parameter createdDate
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/sql/Timestamp; for parameter updatedDate
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/VisitType; for parameter visitType
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/VisitType;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: com.param.entity.model.master.VisitType(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key com.param.entity.model.master.VisitType(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/sql/Timestamp; for parameter createdDate
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/sql/Timestamp; for parameter updatedDate
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for type Ljava/sql/Timestamp;
    INFO : springfox.documentation.schema.property.ModelPropertiesKeyGenerator - Cache key generated: java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    INFO : springfox.documentation.spring.web.caching.CachingAspect - Caching aspect applied for cache modelProperties with key java.sql.Timestamp(false)
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/util/List<Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;>; for parameter kinDetailsList
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding collectionElement type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Recursively resolving dependencies for collectionElement type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/KinDetail;
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding type Ljava/util/List<Lcom/param/entity/model/master/State;>; for parameter stateList
    DEBUG: springfox.documentation.schema.ModelDependencyProvider - Adding collectionElement type Lcom/param/entity/model/master/State;
....
....
```

Their may be some hibernate relation issue, but due to application size, I am unable to find out which relation causing this problem.

So can anybody please help me by looking at these logs,

> 1. What are these logs are?
> 2. And how to find wrong hibernate relations, if any?
> 3. It must be some configuration issue(so server starup time more than 10 min)

Note: 
1. I have already setup `default-lazy-init="true"`

2. mentioned best possible specific `component-scan base-package`
3. checked for `@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)`

Comment: Try to log hibernate queries and count them. Perhaps profiling on database side could help too.

Comment: @Luis, yes tried log hibernate queries, but wont found any. All the logs are of springfox.

Comment: Logging hibernate queries it's kind of tricky but possible. Unfortunately don't have a howto at hand right now.

Comment: @Santosh Kumbhoje Are you able to find a solution for it.. right now I am also facing the same issue.. Any help is much appreciated.